# How i can fix problem with React (A component is changing a controlled input of type undefined to be uncontrolled.)?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I redid my application. When you click on the button, a modal window should appear, but it gives an error" A component is changing a controlled input of type undefined to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component."

HiddenFormState.js:

```
    let Formdates = {
    OnNameChanged:"",
    OnEmailChanged:"",
    OnPhoneChanged:"",
    OnMessageChanged:"",
    isFormVisible:false
}
const FormState = (state = Formdates, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FormState' :
            return !{...state,isFormVisible:{...state.isFormVisible}};
        case "OnNameChangedHidden":
            return {...state,OnNameChanged:action.NewText}
        case "OnEmailChangedHidden":
            return {...state,OnEmailChanged:action.NewText}
        case "OnPhoneChangedHidden":
            return {...state,OnPhoneChanged:action.NewText}
        case "OnMessageChangedHidden":
            return {...state,OnMessageChanged:action.NewText}
        case 'FormSendHidden' :
            return !state;
        default :
            return {...state};
    }
};
export let HiddenForm =()=> ({
    type: "FormState"
})
export let OnNameChangedCreator = (NewText) => ({
    type: "OnNameChangedHidden",
    NewText:NewText
})
export let SendForm = () => ({
    type: "SendFormHidden"
})
export let OnMessageChangedCreator  = (NewText) => ({
    type: "OnMessageChangedHidden",
    NewText:NewText
})
export let OnPhoneChangedCreator  = (NewText) => ({
    type: "OnPhoneChangedHidden",
    NewText:NewText
})
export let OnEmailChangedCreator = (NewText) => ({
    type: "OnEmailChangedHidden",
    NewText:NewText
})
export default FormState;
```

Container component:

```
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import MainFirst from "./main-first";
import  {
    HiddenForm, OnEmailChangedCreator,
    OnMessageChangedCreator,
    OnNameChangedCreator,
    OnPhoneChangedCreator
} from "../../store/hiddenFormState";

let MapStateToProps=state=>{
    return{
        Name:state.FormState.OnNameChanged,
        Email:state.FormState.OnEmailChanged,
        Phone:state.FormState.OnPhoneChanged,
        Message:state.FormState.OnMessageChanged,
        IsFormVisible:state.FormState.IsFormVisible
    }
}
let MainFirstContainer = connect(MapStateToProps, {HiddenForm,OnPhoneChangedCreator,OnNameChangedCreator,OnEmailChangedCreator,OnMessageChangedCreator})(MainFirst)
export default MainFirstContainer
```

Component:

```
import React from "react";
import "./../../css/App.css";
import Main1 from "./../../Images/Main1.jpg";
import HiddenForm from "./hidden-form.js";
class MainFirst extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <div className="firstMain">
          <div className="cover" />
          <div className="firstMain-block">
            <h1>text</h1>
            <p>text</p>
            <button id="b" onClick={this.props.HiddenForm}>text</button>
            <button id="s" onClick={this.props.HiddenForm}>text</button>
          </div>
          <img className="Main1" src={Main1} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div className={(this.props.IsFormVisible)? "visible-form Chagebleform":"hidden-form Chagebleform"}>
          <HiddenForm OnNameChangedCreator={this.props.OnNameChangedCreator}
                      OnMessageChangedCreator={this.props.OnMessageChangedCreator}
                      OnPhoneChangedCreator={this.props.OnPhoneChangedCreator}
                      OnEmailChangedCreator={this.props.OnEmailChangedCreator}
                      Name={this.props.Name}
                      Email={this.props.Email}
                      Phone={this.props.Phone}
                      Message={this.props.Message} HiddenForm={this.props.HiddenForm}/>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
export default MainFirst;
```

css:

```
.Chagebleform {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    animation: fadeIn ease .5s;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease .5s;
    -moz-animation: fadeIn ease .5s;
    -o-animation: fadeIn ease .5s;
    -ms-animation: fadeIn ease .5s;
    text-align: center;
}

.hidden-form {
    display: none;
}
.visible-form {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the css and the HiddenForm component code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in the reducer where you invert the visibility of the form. Try this:

```
case 'FormState':
  return {
    ...state,
    isFormVisible: !state.isFormVisible
  }
```

Comment: The error has disappeared, but the script does not work

Comment: I registered debugger and found that isVisibleForm is undefind,
but I don’t know why

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for an answer to this: 
If you are getting this error while using react/redux, check your reducers. Usually, when I encounter this error it is because of some silly mistake I've made in a complex reducer return statement.

An example of a recent bug for me:

```
case ActionTypes.SET_RUNE_DETAILS:
  return {
    ...state,
    tiers: state.tiers.map((tier, tierId) =>
      tierId === action.payload.tierId
        ? {
            ...tier,
            runes: state.tiers.map((rune, id) =>
              id === action.payload.id ? { ...rune, detail: action.payload.value } : rune,
            ),
          }
        : tier,
    ),
  }
```

This threw the error in question. The answer was to change one line:

```
case ActionTypes.SET_RUNE_DETAILS:
  return {
    ...state,
    tiers: state.tiers.map((tier, tierId) =>
      tierId === action.payload.tierId
        ? {
            ...tier,
            runes: tier.runes.map((rune, id) =>
              id === action.payload.id ? { ...rune, detail: action.payload.value } : rune,
            ),
          }
        : tier,
    ),
  }
```

In the 1st version, the reducer was attempting to change the value of the wrong attribute in state, causing the error message.

In OP's case, I see a couple of errors in the reducer

1. `case 'FormSendHidden' : return !state;`
2. `return !{...state,isFormVisible:{...state.isFormVisible}};`